# Google Static Map API error - java.io.IOException : No Response Entries Available

Tags: java-me, gps, google-maps-static-api

I am Developing GPS based app in J2ME . I am new in the Google API coding. When I give command to map one after another for example Up, Down, zoom, zoom-out the Google Static Map API gives me the Following error at this code - `inputStream = connection.openInputStream();` :

> java.io.IOException: No Response Entries Available
>
> null

```
at com.sun.midp.io.InternalConnector.openPrim(+157)
at com.sun.midp.io.InternalConnector.openInternal(+9)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect_wap(+210)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.connect(+107)
at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.openInputStream(+64)
at midletgps.GoogleMaps.run(GoogleMaps.java:90)
```

What is the meaning of this error & how should I resolved that?? Plz help me.. I stucked here because of this problem...

My connection code is as follows :

```
//the query string for the Google service
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=";
url += latitude + "," + longitude;
url += "&zoom=" + String.valueOf(zoom);
url += "&size=" + width + "x" + height + "&maptype=hybrid" +"&sensor=true" + "&key=API key";
try 
{
    connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
    map = Image.createImage(inputStream);
    setImage(map);
    iserror=false;
    repaint();
    midGPS.displayMap();
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{        
    iserror=true;
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try 
    {
        if (connection != null) 
        {
             connection.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

I developed a code the way said but problem is still persist.. Code is

```
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=";
    url += latitude + "," + longitude;
    url += "&zoom=" + String.valueOf(zoom);
    url += "&size=" + width + "x" + height + "&maptype=hybrid" +"&sensor=true" + "&key=API key";
    try 
    {
        Image logo = null;
        byte[] imagedata;`

        connection = (ContentConnection)Connector.open(url);
        inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();

        int len = (int) connection.getLength();
        if(len != -1)
        {
            imagedata = new byte[len]; 

            //get the image into byte 
            inputStream.readFully(imagedata);
        }
        else //length not available 
        {
            byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) 
            {
               byteArray.write(c);
            }   
            imagedata = byteArray.toByteArray();
            byteArray.close();
        }

        //create an Image object
        logo = Image.createImage(imagedata, 0, imagedata.length);
        setImage(logo);
        iserror=false;
        repaint();
        midGPS.displayMap();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {        
        iserror=true;
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //showError("Error message : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try 
        {
              if (connection != null) 
              {
                   connection.close();
              }
                      if (inputStream != null) 
              {
                   inputStream.close();
              }
                      if (byteArray != null) 
              {
                   connection.close();
              }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            showError("Error message : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

My complete code for google maps as follows -

```
public class GoogleMaps extends Canvas implements CommandListener, Runnable 

{

    //get the width and the height of the screen

    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();           
    Image map;
    Command cmdBack = new Command("Back", Command.EXIT, 1);
    Command cmdRefresh = new Command("Refresh", Command.SCREEN, 1);
    MidletGPS midGPS; //reference to the parent MIDlet 
    int zoom = 17;   
    String latitude = "";
    String longitude = "";
    ContentConnection connection = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null; 
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = null;
    Thread t;
    boolean iserror = true;
    Alert error;`

    public GoogleMaps(MidletGPS mGPS, String Lat, String Longit) 
    {
    //only for testing    
    latitude = "19.021531";    
    longitude = "72.848432";
    //latitude = Lat;
    //longitude = Longit; 
    midGPS = mGPS;
        this.addCommand(cmdBack);
        this.addCommand(cmdRefresh);
        this.setCommandListener(this);
        runThread();
    }   

    public void runThread()
    {
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void setImage(Image image)
    {
        map = image;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
       //Paints only, if the search succeeded in returning a location
        if(!iserror) 
        {
            g.drawImage(map, width/2, height/2, Graphics.HCENTER | Graphics.VCENTER);
        }
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) 
    {
        if (c == cmdBack) 
    {
         midGPS.setCurrentForm(midGPS.mainForm);
    }
    if (c == cmdRefresh) 
    {
            runThread();
        this.repaint();
    }
    }   

    public void run()
    {   

        //the query string for the Google service
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=";
    url += latitude + "," + longitude;
    url += "&zoom=" + String.valueOf(zoom);
    url += "&size=" + width + "x" + height + "&maptype=hybrid" +"&sensor=true" + "&key=API KEY";
    try 
        {
            Image logo = null;
            byte[] imagedata;

            connection = (ContentConnection)Connector.open(url);
            if(inputStream.read() != -1)
            {
                inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();
            }
            else
            {

            }

            int len = (int) connection.getLength();
            if(len != -1)
            {
                imagedata = new byte[len]; 

                //get the image into byte 
                inputStream.readFully(imagedata);
            }
            else //length not available 
            {
                byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c;
        while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) 
                {
                   byteArray.write(c);
        }   
                imagedata = byteArray.toByteArray();
                byteArray.close();
            }

            //create an Image object
            logo = Image.createImage(imagedata, 0, imagedata.length);
            setImage(logo);
            iserror=false;
            repaint();
            midGPS.displayMap();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {        
            iserror=true;
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //showError("Error message : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
            try 
        {
        if (connection != null) 
        {
            connection.close();
        }
                if (inputStream != null) 
        {
            inputStream.close();
        }
                if (byteArray != null) 
        {
            byteArray.close();
        }
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                showError("Error message : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    }

    protected void keyPressed(int keyCode)
    {
        if (((char) keyCode) == '1') 
        {
       zoom--;    
    }
    if (((char) keyCode) == '3')
        {
       zoom++;  
    }
    //if you want to move the map in all directions
    double offset = 0.02;
    if (getGameAction(keyCode) == 5)
        {
            double lon = (Double.parseDouble(longitude));
            lon += offset / zoom;
        longitude = String.valueOf(lon);
        }
    if (getGameAction(keyCode) == 2) 
        {
        double lon = (Double.parseDouble(longitude));
        lon -= offset / zoom;
        longitude = String.valueOf(lon);
    }
    if (getGameAction(keyCode) == 4) 
        {
        double lat = (Double.parseDouble(latitude));
        lat += offset / zoom;
        latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
    }
    if (getGameAction(keyCode) == 6)
        {
        double lat = (Double.parseDouble(latitude));
        lat -= offset / zoom;
        latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
    }

        // re-Call connection thread 
        runThread();

    //call the paint event
    //this.repaint();
     }

    void showError(String message)
    {
    error = new Alert("Error", message, null, AlertType.ERROR);
        error.setTimeout(error.getDefaultTimeout());
    Display.getDisplay(midGPS).setCurrent(error, midGPS.mainForm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, does this failure occur every time you run the application?  For example, try rebooting your phone.  Then run this code.  Do you see this exception the first time you run?

Comment: Yes this failure occur every time when I run app & after rebooting the phone too.... But when I run the app first time this error not occurred that time, because that time I didn't gave immediate commands to map one after another... & this problem is because of this..

Comment: And I also want to remind you that third solution is suggest me is for   downloading single image from server & here in my app I have to download map image continuously... till user interact with app without any error..

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  *Continuously*?  You are just requesting an image multiple times, right?  So, you call the `getImage()` method I suggested multiple times?  How often are you doing this?  Once a second?  Once a minute?  If you're doing this in a loop, then please show that loop, too.

Comment: If you are calling the method to request the image too quickly, I'm wondering if the device is running out of resources, since your connection or input streams might not get completely deleted when closed (garbage collection).  The other thing I notice is that it appears that you are making your network connection on the UI thread, which is never good.

Comment: Yess you are right I am requesting an image multiple times.. but my meaning of saying **continuously** is that whenever we zoom, moves the map left or right, it shows new Map Image right....!? & I am checking that if user want to search of his/her desired place & if he/she immediate any of the command one after another that time this error is going to appear... therefore I want to overcome or want to handle this error successfully without collapsing app... now are you got my point??? To clear your another doubts I pasted my entire code above... I think this will help you to understand my code

Comment: You didn't exactly use the code that I suggested.  You changed it, to make `connection` and `inputStream` *member variables*.  I would not recommend doing that.  Make them *local* variables in the method that uses them.  Also, you should include some protection so that if a map request is running (`run()` is running), then another user action should either cancel the current request, or wait until the current request ends.  As the code is now, you can have concurrent requests, which probably isn't good.

Comment: Also, I take back my comment that you're making your network connection on the UI thread.  Your edit shows me that you're not.  But, what you are doing is modifying variables used in the UI, on the background thread, without any kind of locking/protection.  I don't think that's causing the `No Response Entries Available` problem, but it is another problem with this code.

Comment: You said  that, **I am modifying variables used in the UI, on the background thread**, I don't understand your this comment. Please Can you explain it little bit briefly...

Comment: I don't know that it's safe to modify your `map`  on the background thread, and have it painted on the UI thread.  If you look at [this excerpt from J2ME in a Nutshell](http://books.google.com/books?id=ieBA3-Q-V6sC&pg=PA178&lpg=PA178&dq=thread+safety+in+J2ME+midlet&source=bl&ots=ONgpeb4xbl&sig=4aWxBbEbPWxr8j1jbsJoKLBurRs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=miQOUc21PIjWiAKisICgCg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA), it suggests that using `callSerially()` may be one way to protect this.  However, we're getting off topic.  SO isn't really intended for real-time tech support, and I've already given quite a few suggestions on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would debug this:

**1.** First, make sure you copy your whole URL string (including the coordinates and API key that I can't double-check for you), and paste the URL into a **desktop** browser.  First, make sure you can retrieve the image that way.  If not, your URL is bad.

**2.** If step (1) works, I would try checking the status of your request using a couple methods:

```java
connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) { // check HTTP code
   inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
   int len = (int) connection.getLength();  
   if (len > 0) {                              // check content length
       map = Image.createImage(inputStream);
```

Make sure the HTTP response code looks OK, and the stream opens, yielding a positive content length.  Your code probably won't make it to the length check, based on the stack trace you show, but it might be useful debugging ... and there always might be more than one problem.

**3.** If you're still stuck, you might try [an alternate implementation of the code to retrieve a URL and load it into an `Image` object](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/wi-pdaimages/section3.html).  Take note that the stream and connection are **local** variables in this method, and thus can be garbage collected sometime after the method ends.

```java
private Image getImage(String url) throws IOException
{
    ContentConnection connection = (ContentConnection) Connector.open(url);

    DataInputStream iStrm = connection.openDataInputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = null;
    Image im = null;

    try
    {
      // ContentConnection includes a length method
      byte imageData[];
      int length = (int) connection.getLength();
      if (length != -1)
      {
        imageData = new byte[length];

        // Read the png into an array
        iStrm.readFully(imageData);
      }
      else  // Length not available...
      {
        bStrm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int ch;
        while ((ch = iStrm.read()) != -1)
          bStrm.write(ch);

        imageData = bStrm.toByteArray();
        bStrm.close();
      }

      // Create the image from the byte array
      im = Image.createImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
    }
    finally
    {
      // Clean up
      if (iStrm != null)
        iStrm.close();
      if (connection != null)
        connection.close();
      if (bStrm != null)
        bStrm.close();
    }
    return (im == null ? null : im);
}
```

**Update:** also, take a look [at this Nokia J2ME documentation for using the REST Maps API](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_the_RESTful_Map_API_with_Java_ME).  Take note of this warning:

> The important point here is to make sure that all connections are
>   closed regardless of the success or failure of the request. Failure to
>   do this basic housekeeping results in the connection failing after a
>   few requests with a "No Response Entries Available" error. Once an
>   image is received, it is held as a static image in the im Object.

So, if you're going to keep your original code, make sure to do this in your `finally` block:

```java
finally {
    try {
        if (inputStream != null) 
             inputStream.close();

        if (connection != null) 
             connection.close();           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Rahul, did you try my suggestion (1) and (2), or just (3)?  Also, see my additional suggestion about closing the **InputStream** in your `finally` block.

Comment: @ Nate, Yes Nate.... I tried all of three suggestions... and your third suggestion is based on that additional suggestion. If you noticed whatever code I developed is based on that third & additional suggestion & I think I developed a correct code... but still it is giving me a problem at inputstream...

Comment: @Rahul, Take a look at the follow-up question I posted under your question above ... have you tried that?

Comment: @ Nate, is that possible to check inputstream like connaction checking as you shown in 2nd suggestion??? because inputstream throws IOException & I have also getting IOException...

Comment: @Rahul, I'm also not clear on your last comment here.  Are you referring to the suggestion I label **2.** above?  Checking `getLength()` or `getResponseCode()`?  No, those methods don't exist for an `InputStream`.  I was, however, suggesting that you should call `close()` on the `inputStream`, which you did not have in your original code, but you did have in the update to your question (although in a different *order*).

Comment: No.. no I just want to know that is there any method or property which checks that inputstream is completely field or not thats why gave jsut an example of connection. I think the error is because of more data is coming than size of the inputstream.. thats why ask....

Comment: @Rahul, `InputStream` objects don't have a size.  That's what makes it a *stream*.  So, you don't need to worry about that.  But, you should make sure it's closed, and deleted.  The `inputStream` variable (or `iStrm` in `getImage()`) should be a *local* variable, not a *member variable*.

Comment: Problem solved Nate.... The problem is in thread. I drop the thread implementation & re-create entire code again as per your 3rd suggestion n now my its working properly.... Very Very Thanx a lot Nate to support me and suggest me... I hope you will continuously support in this way..... Thanx a lot... take care...

Comment: @Rahul, you're welcome.  Don't forget to vote for the answer, too, if it was helpful.  Of course, you don't have to vote for answers, but it does help say *thanks*, and identify to others which answers worked best.  If something in one of my comments was the key to your solution, though, feel free to let me know, and I can move it up to the actual *answer*.